# Would synchronising on class object block the entire class (and its members)

Tags: java, static, synchronize

Would this block all access to `Foo` and its static members while the statements in the class is executing?

```
MyBlock:
synchronize(Foo.class)
{
    // ... do something 
}
```

In other words, while `MyBlock` is executing, no other thread would be able to call any static methods in `Foo`, right?

Ok, if this does not do it. Then how do I stop a class and its members from being accessed for a certain amount of time?
Thanks

Comment: no. that's not how synchronization works. basically, the object on which you take the lock is irrelevant by itself. it holds meaning only if several thread try to take a lock on the same object.

Comment: also : you could have tried this, too.

Comment: Wrong. It would block all execution paths wich lock on the same class object, nothing else. There is no such thing as "blocking a class"

Comment: @MarioStoilov not a duplicate, this question has nothing to do with child classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The use of the lock object itself, the `Foo.class` object in this case, is unaffected by synchronized blocks using it as a lock object.

You can't stop classes from using being used, unless you put them behind something like a proxy that controls access, or make the methods themselves conditionally block execution internally, which doesn't really prevent access but simulates it.

Comment: (Just updated my question).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock on static members, you can define a dummy static member to wich you can lock, and every time you want to access the static members, you'll just check if that dummy member is locked.

```
class Foo{
     public static Integer dummyLock;
....
}
```

afterwhich you can:
MyBlock:

```
synchronize(Foo.dummyLock)
{
    // ... access static members here
}
```